# How can I stack 2 calculated fields into 1 Stacked bar chart instead of overlaping them?

Tags: visualization, tableau-desktop

Im having a bad problem. Im using dual axis with 2 calculated fields but they are overlaping the other instead of stacking above.

I have been googling but found no solution. Can you show me the solution? Thank guys.
Reality:
[image]
Expect:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are trying to get, you need to turn-off "Stack Marks" option from the "Analysis" menu on the top.

You can refer more details here: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/stacked-bar-chart-multiple-measures

and this for more details : https://www.rigordatasolutions.com/post/stacked-bar-chart-in-tableau